# Sql Min Max range With over function?

Tags: sql, hive

I have many users and Date time column. I would like to know the min and max values of each users for each year and each month?

```
name      date        Income     Expense
Vijay     12-10-2017    10         8
Vijay     16-04-2017    25         12  

year(date) as Y_year,
month(date) as M_Month,
```

I tried the code below but no use either

```
min(Income)over( PARTITION by (name, Y_year,M_Month)) as min_income_of_month,
Max(Expense)over( PARTITION by (name, Y_year,M_Month)) as Max_Expense_of__month
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide both sample data and desired results.  What does the original data look like?

Comment: What about `min(Income) over (partition by name, year(date), month(date))` ? ;).

Comment: Thank a lot :) It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select name, year(date) as Y_year, month(date) as M_Month,
       min(income), max(income), min(expense), max(expense)
from t
group by name, year(date), month(date)
order by name, Y_year, M_Month;
```

Comment: Thanks :) This works just I  wanted  to compute it using the window function .

Answer (score 0):

Just use min and max function on the columns you want to aggregate and group by user and the month of the date

No need to use window functions